# Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 Metadata ( in terms of folder structure and size information) into Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake

On Azure portal - I have couple of "Data Lake Storage Gen1" resource and I need to build a Power BI Dashboard that can show the 
1. Storage Information  ( how much of data resides on the resource) 
2. Storage Information at folder level ( at least until Level-2 ) , something like below
Parent_Folder (10TB)
    Sub_Folder_1 (3TB)
    Sub_Folder_2 (6TB)
    Sub_Folder_3(1TB)

This data should be displayed in Power BI as a report - so that we can have multiple users view this data.

I understand - currently thsi is available in Azure portal - but here is a ask to make it easy for some platform and operations team to get it via Power BI Dashbaord - so that they dont need to get access onto Azure portal and look for navigating to this resource.

Is this feasible ? If yes - can you help me out with what option -I can retrieve this meta data from ADLS and what credentials/role should be granted on the resource in Azure portal ?

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 1):

You can get the meta data from the Azure Datalake Store API. More details in the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis

It will return a JSON object.

It will give file sizes based on folders it also outline the permissions you need. I would set up a data flow to hit the API then transform the returned JSON in to something useful. You could also if you are using ADL and are using Azure Datalake Analytics or Azure Databricks use those to get the list of folder and iterate though the them to get the information.